# Optimizing a divide-and-conquer algorithm for counting inversions

Tags: beginner, algorithm, array, haskell, divide-and-conquer

I have the following code:

```
inversions :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Int
inversions xs = snd $ countInv' (xs, length xs)

countInv' :: (Ord a) => ([a], Int) -> ([a], Int)
countInv' ([], _) = ([], 0)
countInv' ([x], _) = ([x], 0)
countInv' (xs, n) = (sorted, leftInv + splitInv + rightInv)
    where
        leftLen = n `div` 2
        rightLen = n - leftLen
        (left, right) = splitAt leftLen xs
        (sortedLeft, leftInv) = countInv' (left, leftLen)
        (sortedRight, rightInv) = countInv' (right, rightLen)
        (sorted, splitInv) = countSplitInv' (sortedLeft, leftLen) (sortedRight, rightLen)

countSplitInv' :: (Ord a) => ([a], Int) -> ([a], Int) -> ([a], Int)
countSplitInv' ([], _) ([], _) = ([], 0)
countSplitInv' (xs, _) ([], _) = (xs, 0)
countSplitInv' ([], _) (xs, _) = (xs, 0)
countSplitInv' (x : xs, nx) (y : ys, ny)
    | x > y     = (y : sortedY, nx + splitInvY)
    | otherwise = (x : sortedX, splitInvX)
    where
        (sortedX, splitInvX) = countSplitInv' (xs, pred nx) (y : ys, ny)
        (sortedY, splitInvY) = countSplitInv' (x : xs, nx) (ys, pred ny)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    contents <- getContents
    print $ inversions (map read (lines contents) :: [Int])
```

How could I write this code in a way that is more idiomatic, reduces the amount of repetition, and reduces the amount of data being copied?

As a Haskell beginner, I would appreciate it if you give an indepth explanation of the code you write and try to keep your code as simple as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `countSplitInv'` is that merging two lists is has the characteristic of [co-recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion) (it consumes a finite amount of data from given lists to produce one output element), while computing the inversion count has the characteristic of recursion (accumulates value while traversing given lists).

One way how to remedy that would be to count the inversion count for each element separately. Then we'd be working with lists of `[(a, Int)]`. This also somewhat simplifies the code as it's not necessary to wrap/unwrap pairs at so many places. Also using [as-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1153465/1333025) we can avoid recombining values unnecessarily.

```
import Criterion.Main

inversions :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Int
inversions xs = sum . map snd $ countInv' xs (length xs)

countInv' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Int -> [(a, Int)]
countInv' []  _ = []
countInv' [x] _ = [(x, 0)]
countInv' xs  n =
    countSplitInv' (countInv' left leftLen) leftLen (countInv' right rightLen)
  where
    leftLen = n `div` 2
    rightLen = n - leftLen
    (left, right) = splitAt leftLen xs

-- we only need to keep track of the right part (nx)
countSplitInv' :: (Ord a) => [(a, Int)] -> Int -> [(a, Int)] -> [(a, Int)]
-- note that the case  [] _ [] is contained in xs _ []
countSplitInv' xs _ [] = xs
countSplitInv' [] _ ys = ys
countSplitInv' xs@((x, ix) : xs') nx ys@((y, iy) : ys')
    | x > y     = (y, iy + nx) : countSplitInv' xs nx ys'
    | otherwise = (x, ix)      : countSplitInv' xs' (nx - 1) ys


main = defaultMain [
    bgroup "inv" $ map bstep [1..10]
  ]
  where
    bstep n = bench (show n2) $ nf inversions [n2,n2-1..1]
      where n2 = 2^n
```

(I also added `main` for measuring performance using the [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) package.)

This way, `countSplitInv'` is just co-recursive. According to my benchmarks (compiling with `-O2` and running `main`), for a decreasing list of length 1024 the original took 1.55ms, while this improved version takes 0.96ms.

However, we still do `splitAt` and computing the length of the list at the beginning. A way to solve that is dividing the list not from the top, but the bottom. The trick is to first convert `[a]` into a list of singletons `[[a]]` and then merge them pair-wise until we get to a single element. (See also [the source of Haskell's standard `sort`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html#sort).) It can be implemented in many ways. Since I like the abstraction of [monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid), I used a monoid that keeps track of inversion counts of a list of elements, and the monoid operation is merging such two lists. And `mconcat` is implemented pair-wise so that the order of computations form a balanced binary tree:

```
import Data.Monoid
import Criterion.Main

countSplitInv' :: (Ord a) => [(a, Int)] -> Int -> [(a, Int)] -> [(a, Int)]
countSplitInv' xs _ [] = xs
countSplitInv' [] _ ys = ys
countSplitInv' xs@((x, ix) : xs') nx ys@((y, iy) : ys')
    | x > y     = (y, iy + nx) : countSplitInv' xs nx ys'
    | otherwise = (x, ix)      : countSplitInv' xs' (nx - 1) ys

-- Represents a computation of inversions.
data Inv a = Inv { invSize   :: !Int        -- ^ the length of the list
                 , invSorted :: [(a, Int)]  -- ^ sorted elements with their
                                            -- inversion counts
                 }

instance (Ord a) => Monoid (Inv a) where
    mempty = Inv 0 []
    mappend (Inv nx xs) (Inv ny ys) = Inv (nx + ny) (countSplitInv' xs nx ys)
    mconcat []  = mempty
    mconcat [x] = x
    mconcat xs  = mconcat (mergePairs xs)
      where
        mergePairs (x:y:zs) = (x `mappend` y) : mergePairs zs
        mergePairs zs       = zs

inject :: a -> Inv a
inject x = Inv 1 [(x, 0)]

inversions :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Int
inversions = sum . map snd . invSorted . mconcat . map inject


main = defaultMain [
    bgroup "inv" $ map bstep [1..10]
  ]
  where
    bstep n = bench (show n2) $ nf inversions [n2,n2-1..1]
      where n2 = 2^n
```

This variant is again faster, it takes 0.66ms for 1024 element list.

And if we use the same trick `sort` does (see the above link), and partition the input list into decreasing and increasing sequences (for which we can easily compute the inversion counts in linear time), we get somewhat more complex code, but very fast for lists that contain long ordered sequences:

```
import Data.Monoid
import Criterion.Main

countSplitInv' :: (Ord a) => [(a, Int)] -> Int -> [(a, Int)] -> [(a, Int)]
countSplitInv' xs _ [] = xs
countSplitInv' [] _ ys = ys
countSplitInv' xs@((x, ix) : xs') nx ys@((y, iy) : ys')
    | x > y     = (y, iy + nx) : countSplitInv' xs nx ys'
    | otherwise = (x, ix)      : countSplitInv' xs' (nx - 1) ys

-- Represents a computation of inversions.
data Inv a = Inv { invSize   :: !Int        -- ^ the length of the list
                 , invSorted :: [(a, Int)]  -- ^ sorted elements with their
                                            -- inversion counts
                 }

instance (Ord a) => Monoid (Inv a) where
    mempty = Inv 0 []
    mappend (Inv nx xs) (Inv ny ys) = Inv (nx + ny) (countSplitInv' xs nx ys)
    mconcat []  = mempty
    mconcat [x] = x
    mconcat xs  = mconcat (mergePairs xs)
      where
        mergePairs (x:y:zs) = (x `mappend` y) : mergePairs zs
        mergePairs zs       = zs


sequences :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [Inv a]
sequences (a:b:xs)
  | a > b      = descending b [a] 2 xs
  | otherwise  = ascending  b (a:) 2 xs
  where
sequences [x] = [Inv 1 [(x, 0)]]
sequences []  = []

descending :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> Int -> [a] -> [Inv a]
descending a as n (b:bs)
  | a > b             = descending b (a:as) (n + 1) bs
descending a as n bs  = Inv n (zip (a:as) [(n-1),(n-2)..]) : sequences bs

ascending :: (Ord a) => a -> ([a] -> [a]) -> Int -> [a] -> [Inv a]
ascending a as n (b:bs)
  | a < b             = ascending b (\ys -> as (a:ys)) (n + 1) bs
ascending a as n bs   = Inv n (zip (as [a]) [(n-1),(n-2)..]) : sequences bs

inversions :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Int
inversions = sum . map snd . invSorted . mconcat . sequences


main = defaultMain [
    bgroup "inv" $ map bstep [1..10]
  ]
  where
    bstep n = bench (show n2) $ nf inversions [n2,n2-1..1]
      where n2 = 2^n
```

(For the decreasing list of 1024 numbers, it took 0.11ms, as it computed the result in one single pass.)

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! I haven't done monoids yet, so I don't understand everything after the use of monoids. I will read up on monoids before I look further into your answer.

Comment: @wei2912 For monoids see also [What is practical use of monoids?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26230530/1333025) and [Examples of monoids/semigroups in programming](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2482582/1333025).

Answer (score 2):

Well, a simple implementation would be:

```
inversions' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Int 
inversions' []  = 0
inversions' [_] = 0
inversions' (x:xs) =
  (length $ filter (< x) xs) + (inversions' xs)
```

But that would be an \$O(n^2)\$ algorithm, as you probably knew, since you seem to have written your code with performance in mind.  In fact, you've gone to great lengths (no pun intended) to avoid calling `length` more than once: with every list that you pass around, you also keep track of its length.

I'm not sure how much performance gain such bookkeeping gives you in practice.  You still need to call `splitAt` with every subdivision, which is \$O(n)\$.  For simplicity, I suspect that you would be better off copying your input into a `Data.Vector`, and using vectors everywhere instead.

Essentially, what you have is a mergesort that counts inversions instead of producing the sorted list.  My simplistic implementation is analogous to an insertion sort.

Comment: `length` is \$O(n)\$ according to the docs. A casual benchmark test (which is by no means accurate) revealed that my program took about 12 seconds with `length` and less than 2 without `length`, so it appears that not using `length` makes a significant difference. I will take a look at `Data.Vector`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A trivial simplification would be to eliminate this redundant special case:

```
countSplitInv' ([], _) ([], _) = ([], 0)
```